# How to delete a node from Neo4j databse with python 3.6

Tags: python, database, neo4j, nodes

I've trying to delete a node from neo4j database, using python code but I can't get to work. I've tried a few things and yet nothing.

This is the documentation in Neo4j to delete a node:

```
MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n
```

I've searched online for examples, but I don't know how code this same lines in python.

[Nodes relationships and characteristics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP9gS.jpg)

This is an image of my nodes, I only want to delete the red ones. How do I delete just one of them?

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to MATCH the label of the red nodes and a property of the one you want to delete.

MATCH (n:RED_LABEL) 
WHERE n.property = 'something'
DETACH DELETE n